# Sorting by number of records which match a certain field in mongodb. (Finding duplicates)

Tags: mongodb

I want to build an index on a field in my user collection. The field was supposed to be unique, but it was enforced at the server level, rather than database level. Mongodb has warned me that the field is not unique; there must be records with duplicate 'slug' (the field which I want to make unique).

What's the best way to find out which records have duplicates (matched by the field 'slug'?

Answer (score 0):

Use aggregation on slug and get slug with count > 1:

```
db.user.aggregate(
    {"$group" : { "_id": "$slug", "count": { "$sum": 1 } } },
    {"$match": {"_id" :{ "$ne" : null } , "count" : {"$gt": 1} } }, 
    {"$project": {"slug" : "$_id", "_id" : 0} }
)
```